# How to put form fields into FieldGroup's using userforms module

Tags: forms, silverstripe

I'd like to do a customised layout for a form which involves putting form fields into a number of FieldGroup's. The end goal is to let the user add fields to the form, and for each field they can choose which group it will appear in (eg the wide section of the form at the top, or the left or right lower sections of the form which are split into 2 columns).

Is it possible to extend the [userforms module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms) to achieve this, and how might it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the fork I have made to Userforms, This will allow you to assign formfields to columns and have them sit side by side.

https://github.com/helenclarko/silverstripe-userforms

You may be able to edit the EditableCompositeField to add the additions you are after.